# Insert array data to database

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I'm creating my first web app with Symfony.
Now I found a solution for making my code more customizable and extensible.
But for making this solution working in my app I need some help.

Is it possible in Symfony to insert data that is in a key -> value array to a table in the database?

For example, I have an array that looks like:
array('Titel' => 'The Hobbit', 'Music' => 'Add Sheeron')

Now I need to put this into the database table X that looks like:
Titel (varchar (255))
Music (varchar (255))

How can I insert the array into the database? Also the array can contain data that need to be inserted into another table with other Key names.

In other words, how can I map the array key to a field in the database so that I can use it to insert it into the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay let's say your array is called `$music`. and it looks something like this:

```
$music = array('Titel' => 'The Hobbit', 'Music' => 'Add Sheeron');
```

Now you need to create a new instance of your entity which maps to the respective table in your database. For this you need to create a new entity and then persist and flush it.

```
$em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
$music = array('Titel' => 'The Hobbit', 'Music' => 'Add Sheeron');
$entityMusic = new MusicEntity(); //This is your entity
$entityMusic->setTitel($music['title']); //Respective entity methods
$entityMusic->setMusic($music['Music']);
$em->persist($entityMusic);
$em->flush();
```

If you have more than one values you want to insert, you can run a basic for loop to insert all values you want.

For the second part of your question, you will have to look into Relationship and Mapping of Entities. Documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html)

Comment: Is it possible to insert data without using the setters of the entity?
In normal PHP code it looks something like: "INSERT INTO $tableName ($columns) VALUES ($values)";
$columns is in this case array('Titel', 'Music') and $values array('The Hobbit', 'Add Sheeron').

Comment: You can probably use a [native query](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) for that. However it will defeat the purpose of using a framework.

Comment: Ok that was I afraid for. Then It would be using the insert statement of a regular sql.

Comment: That is correct. which is equivalent to writing core PHP

Comment: You can create your Entity and  use `Serializer` component too. [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html)

Answer (score 0):

As I know there is no existing method do to this.

If you want to have auto-binding data you need to use [Symfony forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html). There is also [best practices](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html) for forms.

And if you don't want to use forms you need to bind every field manualy.

Comment: The OP has not mentioned that forms are being used in the problem. Your answer does not make sense.